# Can I connect mixer output female XLR to Mic input of Power Amp?

Tags: amplifiers, mixer

My power amp has only unbalanced inputs (RCA), and the only balanced inputs are the two mic inputs (mic 1 & mic 2). I connected the mixer output (female Left & Right) to the RCA (male RCA left & right) EQ input of the power amp. I noticed that I still hear noises or signal interruption, all my mics are balanced XLRs and already troubleshoot with the inputs in the mixer so I could find where the noises are coming, but it's all fine. My suspicion is that the RCA input picks signals that interrupts signals.

Answer (score 2):

If you turn down the gain on the mic inputs appropriately, they should usually work more or less as balanced line inputs though you want to have any kind of phantom power switched off.

Alternatively, you can use a DI box which should be connectable to either RCA inputs or mic inputs (then you'll want one with attenuation switch) while providing the advantages of a balanced connection.